# Change user's name in KDE

Tags: kde, system-settings, username

I want to setup my real name in 'System Settings' - 'Account Details' - 'Password & User Account' but when I click 'Apply' there is a dialog asking me for my password and I type it correctly but then it says there is an error: 'An error occurred and your name has probably not been changed. The error message was: chfn: Permission denied.'

Comment: To allow chfn to add Real Name in /etc/passwd, open /etc/login.defs (as root) and look for the line containing CHFN_RESTRICT. Change whatever is followed to frwh.
This will allow changing Real Name from KDE System Settings.

Comment: Can you add that as answer below?

Comment: As you can see I can. :)

Answer (score 1):

To allow chfn to add Real Name in /etc/passwd, open /etc/login.defs (as root) and look for the line containing CHFN_RESTRICT. Change whatever is followed to frwh. This will allow changing Real Name from KDE System Settings.